# Visual Studio Shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In VC6 I could navigate between compilation errors with <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Whats the appropriate key in VS2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might prefer to just make Visual Studio use the old v6 keys.  Just say Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard, and select "Visual C++ 6" from the drop-down at the top of that property sheet.

Comment: That's what I did - I also set up all new devs to have this set of keys to aid me when debugging on their machines ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/piyush/archive/2007/03/16/useful-visual-studio-shortcut-keys.aspx) it's <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for C# layout, is this only for VC layout?

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Basic Keyboard Shortcut Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=255B8CF1-F6BD-4B55-BB42-DD1A69315833&displaylang=en)

[Visual C# Keyboard Shortcut Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en)